# Splitting word into syllables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

My intention is to build a simple process with which I can split the word into syllables. The approach is to split the word whenever the vowel occurs. However, the trouble is when a consonant is not followed by a vowel, in such a case the split occurs at that consonant.

My test cases are as follows:

```
hair = ["hair"]
hairai = ["hai", "rai"]
hatred = ["hat", "red"]
```

In the first example hair is one syllable, as the final consonant is not followed by a vowel, similarly, in the final example, the "t" is followed by an r and so should considered along "ha" as one syllable.
In the second example, ai is considered as one vowel sound and so hai will become one syllable.

More examples include

```
father = ["fat", "her"]
kid = ["kid"]
lady = ["la","dy"]
```

Please note that, I am using simplistic examples as the ENglish language is quite complex when it comes to sound

My code is as follows

```js
function syllabify(input) {
  var arrs = [];
  for (var i in input) {
    var st = '';
    var curr = input[i];
    var nxt = input[i + 1];
    if ((curr == 'a') || (curr == 'e') || (curr == 'i') || (curr == 'o') || (curr == 'u')) {
      st += curr;
    } else {
      if ((nxt == 'a') || (nxt == 'e') || (nxt == 'i') || (nxt == 'o') || (nxt == 'u')) {
        st += nxt;
      } else {
        arrs.push(st);
        st = '';
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arrs);
}

syllabify('hatred')
```

However, my code does not even return the strings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have `var st = '';` inside the for-loop.

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your examples. Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What is your logic to **syllabificate**? Please explain your approach first.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I suspected that to be the issue and its one of, but the logic is also skewed. Hence requested for clarification

Comment: @Rajesh True, unless we know the logic of syllabification, it is difficult to suggest a definitive answer.

Comment: PLEASE do not edit vital details based on suggestions in answer/comments. This makes the suggestion void. If the suggestion does not solve the problem, add details explaining it at the end

Comment: So should `hair = ["hair"]` not be `hair = ["hai", "r"]`?

Comment: @venkata compiler/interpreter does not know sounds. *Splitting wherever the vowels occur*, this logic is incorrect.

Comment: @Rajesh On a fundamental level, it is a simple splitting where vowels occur. But when a consonant is not followed by a vowel, then the split should occur at that consonant.

Comment: @venkata This is one of the rules. My advice, try to write random cases with long sentence so you cover more cases

Comment: @venkata that logic seems off

Comment: Describe the difference between `father` and `hatred`.  Why is one `'fa'+'ther'` and the other `'hat'+'red'` using your consonant-vowel approach

Answer (score 16):

## Problems with your current approach

There are a number of problems with your code:

- First thing in the loop, you set `st` to an empty string. This means that you never accumulate any letters. You probably want that line above, *outside* the loop.
- You are trying to loop over the indexes of letters by using `i in input`. In JavaScript, the `in` keyword gives you the keys of an object as strings. So you get strings, not numbers, plus the names of some methods defined on strings. Try `var i = 0; i < input.length; i++` instead.
- Maybe not the direct cause of the problems, but still - your code is messy. How about these?

  - Use clearer names. `currentSyllable` instead of `st`, `syllables` instead of `arrs` and so on.
  - Instead of a nested `if` - `else`, use one `if` - `else if` - `else`.
  - You repeat the same code that checks for vowels twice. Separate it into a function `isVowel(letter)` instead.

## A new approach

Use [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)! Here is your definition of a syllable expressed in regex:

- First, zero or more consonants: `[^aeiouy]*`
- Then, one or more vowels: `[aeiouy]+`
- After that, zero or one of the following:

  - Consonants, followed by the end of the word: `[^aeiouy]*$`
  - A consonant (if it is followed by another consonant): `[^aeiouy](?=[^aeiouy])`

Taken together you get this:

```
/[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy]+(?:[^aeiouy]*$|[^aeiouy](?=[^aeiouy]))?/gi
```

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/At64WO/1). To run it in JavaScript, use the [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function:

```js
const syllableRegex = /[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy]+(?:[^aeiouy]*$|[^aeiouy](?=[^aeiouy]))?/gi;

function syllabify(words) {
    return words.match(syllableRegex);
}

console.log(['away', 'hair', 'halter', 'hairspray', 'father', 'lady', 'kid'].map(syllabify))
```

Note that this does not work for words without vowels. You would either have to modify the regex to accomodate for that case, or do some other workaround.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I updated the example and made it just a little more robust.  Really like this Regex approach, very nice job!

Comment: I haven't had time yet to dig into fixing it yet (sorry) but this regex implementation is probably close for most things but isn't quite right. "fire" (single syllable) is just one example. I suspect it's something to do with the word ending in a vowel?

Comment: @DylanWatson I've tried to use the definition of a syllable you outlined in your question. But I don't think you can define syllables just in terms of consonants and vowels, you need to understand the pronounciation. Both "fire" and "baby" have the same pattern of consonants and wovels, yet one has one syllable and the other two. Teaching a computer to differentiate between those will not be an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

I am weak in the ways of RegEx and while Anders example is right most of the time, I did find a few exceptions.  Here is what I have found to work so far (but I am sure there are other exceptions I have not found yet).  I am sure it can be RegEx'ified by masters of the art.  This function returns an array of syllables.

```
        function getSyllables(word){
        var response = [];
        var isSpecialCase = false;
        var nums = (word.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length;
        //debugger;
        if (isSpecialCase == false && (word.match(/[0123456789]/gi) || []).length == word.length ){
            // has digits
            response.push(word);
            isSpecialCase = true;
        }

        if (isSpecialCase == false && word.length < 4){
            // three letters or less
            response.push(word);
            isSpecialCase = true;
        } 

        if (isSpecialCase == false && word.charAt(word.length-1) == "e"){
            if (isVowel(word.charAt(word.length-2)) == false){
                var cnt = (word.match(/[aeiou]/gi) || []).length;
                if (cnt == 3){
                    if (hasDoubleVowels(word)){
                        // words like "piece, fleece, grease"
                        response.push(word);
                        isSpecialCase = true;
                    }
                }
                if (cnt == 2){
                    // words like "phase, phrase, blaze, name", 
                    if (hasRecurringConsonant(word) == false) {
                    // but not like "syllable"
                    response.push(word);
                    isSpecialCase = true;
                    }

                }                    
            }
        }

        if (isSpecialCase == false){
            const syllableRegex = /[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy]+(?:[^aeiouy]*$|[^aeiouy](?=[^aeiouy]))?/gi;
            response = word.match(syllableRegex);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: ReferenceError: isVowel is not defined